# How to increment the value by 1 using .bat file

Tags: batch-file

I have a rev.bat file. The content of file is:

set v1=10
set v2=20
set v3=1p5
set v4=50
set v5=%v4%

I want to increment the value of v3 by 1 (i.e 1p6).

Below code is update the value by 1 but not this case.

```
@echo off
cd /d D:\
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
::set /p "var=Buildnum "
set "file=rev.bat"
for /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%i in ('findstr "v3= " rev.bat') do (
    set "versionVar=%%~i"
    set "versionVal=%%~j"
    set /a sequence=%%~j+1
)

for /f "tokens=1,*delims=]" %%i in ('type "%file%" ^| find /v /n "" ^& break^>%file%') do (
    set "line=%%j"
    if "!line!" == "!versionVar!=!versionVal!" set line=!versionVar!=!sequence!
    echo(!line!>>!file!
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

This will MOSTLY do it as long as you specifically have a variable that is specific as you have specified.

PowerShell could do a much better job at this.

> If you want the v5=%v4% to work, you will need to do more work. Making
> batch detect the % sign and pass it on will only work once by using
> double percents (v5=%%v4%%).  You will get v5=%v4% in the output file
> and I have no way to detect it as batch strips them which I don't know
> how to correct.

1. I split the line on the = and name them LHS and RHS (left hand side etc..)
2. I look for v3 as the ID on LHS
3. If it isn't v3=xyz, I skip to step #6
4. I take the first two chars off and save them.
5. I take everything else and treat it as a number by incrementing it by 1.  Then put those back together like this `Set RHS=%tmp1%%tmp2%`
6. I put the line it all back together like this `Set OutputString=%LHS%=%RHS%`
7. I write the variable to a TEMP FILE.
8. (currently an echo command) I write the TEMP file over the original file.
9. You should probably delete the temp file.  I didn't bother.

Batch *could* do this much better but would require more effort than it is worth.

```
    @echo off
    Set InputFile=%~DP0\rev.bat
    Set OuputFile=%~DP0\rev.tmp.bat

    :: Clear our output file
    del /f "%OuputFile%"

    for /f "delims=" %%l in ('type %InputFile%') do call :CheckLine "%%l" "%OuputFile%"

    :: Using an echo here because you need to make sure the code works for you
    :: before you use it.  It will clobber the original file with the new one.
    echo copy /y "%OuputFile%" "%InputFile%"
    goto :EOF

::  ----------------------------------------------------------
::  Function CheckLine ---------------------------------------
::  ----------------------------------------------------------

:CheckLine 
    Set InputLine=%~1
    Set OuputFile=%~2

    echo Checking value for %InputLine%
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims== " %%a in ('echo %InputLine%') do set LHS=%%a&&set RHS=%%b

    if /i not "v3" == "%LHS%" goto :NoMod

     Set tmp1=%RHS:~0,2%
     Set tmp2=%RHS:~2%
     Set /a tmp2=%tmp2% +1
     Set RHS=%tmp1%%tmp2%

    :NoMod
    
    Set OutputString=%LHS%=%RHS%
    echo %OutputString% >>%OuputFile%
    goto :EOF
```

Comment: Thanks , @Señor CMasMas ,  Explaination of my code :We get the file content, using find to assign row id's Then we do search and replace and simply remove the row id's. 
Then write back everything to the file including the updated version.


I want that my Rev.bat file having v3=ip5 increment by 1 without removing empty space and special char from the file.it doesn't effect  anything in a file .I had mentioned my file format in a main section .

Comment: ,Thanks for your help, but this code is not works for my case.
The code which I posted is updating the values(which is numeric) without affecting other code.
Is it possible to make changes in that code for  increment v3=1p6 by 1 is helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

See if that would do the job, you have to drag and drop the batch to the other batch.

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set File=C:\my batch\batch.bat
if not exist "%File%" exit

type "%File%" |find /i "v3=" || exit
cls
if exist "%File%.tmp" del /q "%File%.tmp"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type "%File%"') do (
                                           echo %%a |find /i "v3=" 2>nul 1>nul 
                                           if not !errorlevel! EQU 0 (>>"%File%.tmp" echo %%a) else (
                                                                                                   set Line=%%a
                                                                                                   set Number=!Line:~5!
                                                                                                   set /a Number+=1
                                                                                                   set "Line=!Line:~0,5!!Number!"
                                                                                                   >>"%File%.tmp" echo !Line!
                                                                                                  )
                                          )
del /q "%File%"
move "%File%.tmp" "%File%"
```

[image]

Comment: ,How it works for my case,I want my both .bat file will be in different location. and It just update the variable v3=1p6 by 1. As per my understanding there no path of file which I want to update how this code will increment the v3 by 1 without affecting other code instead of updating the string value that I want.

Comment: %1 would be a file that you drag and drop to the batch but instead of this you could also use set File=Somepath+file, it only changes the line where it finds v3= if there is no such line in the batch \ text file it closes the batch right from the start

Comment: ,I tried by set the path(Filepath\file).then I replaced type '%~1' by type %path% . The file even not executing. 
Pls correct me if something is wrong.

Comment: Try now according to the edits I made in the answer....